# Why does function treat NULL as 0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I got this function:

```
Public Function parseSex(ByVal sex As Object) As String
if Not Nothing then
      if sex = 1 Then
         Return "Male"  
      elseif sex = 0 Then
         Return "Female"
      else
         Return "N/D"
      End if
  Else
     Return "N/D"
  End If
End Function
```

Database can return 0, 1 or NULL.
However if this function receives NULL from database it outputs FEMALE,
**Why does this happen and how can it be solved?**

I really need to pass it NULL, 0 or 1

Comment: Which is it?  VBA or VB.NET.  Tag accordingly.  Also, microsoft reporting tag is irrelevant

Comment: And this won't even compile as is.  Fix your code, and properly indent it so we can read it.

Comment: @roryap why wont it compile? PD: i cant test this code, its part of Reporting/Code tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refactor your method as below, replacing the argument with a nullable `Integer` (i.e. `Integer?`) instead of `Object` and replacing the return type with a `Sex` enum:

```
Public Enum Sex
    Male
    Female
    NotDefined
End Enum

Public Function ParseSex(ByVal sex As Integer?) As Sex
    If (sex.HasValue) Then
        Select Case sex.Value
            Case 1
                Return Sex.Male
            Case 0
                Return Sex.Female
            Case Else
                Return Sex.NotDefined
        End Select
    Else
        Return Sex.NotDefined
    End If
End Function
```

If you need to get a string from the return value, just call `ToString()` on it.

In the code you have, your line `if Not Nothing then` is always going to return true.  It doesn't make sense to have it in there.  Also, it's a bad idea to have an `Object` type for the method arg because you could pass it any type of object, but you're assuming it's always going to be an integer and you aren't checking; thus an exception could result.

A few other things I would like to point out to help you improve:

1. Make sure to follow proper naming conventions.  Method names should be upper camel case (Pascal case), .e.g. `ParseSex` not `parseSex`.
2. Always properly indent your code to make it easier to read.  Every nested "block" should be indented with respect to the block that contains it.
3. Make use of the most-specific type possible for your variables; *never* use a type of `Object` unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to pass `sex` as an object? Why can't you pass it as an `integer`?
Like this:

```
Public Function parseSex(ByVal sex As Integer) As String
 if Not Nothing then
 if sex = 1 Then
   Return "Male"   
 elseif sex = 0 Then
   Return "Female"
 else
  Return "N/D"
  End if
  Else
  Return "N/D"
 End If
End Function
```

Or which is the data type of that field in your database?

Comment: still doesnt work, still treats 0 as Female, and yea in database is tinyInt

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you should be checking against DBNull here

```
Public Function parseSex(ByVal sex as integer) as string
if not isDBNull(sex) Then
   if sex = 1 then
      return "Male"
   else
      return "Female"
   end if
   return "N/D"
End If
```

So if null is passed, N/D is returned otherwise it will run the if condition to see if it needs to return Male or Female.